# Inner join on null id select row

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql, inner-join

We have two tables one with ids and one with names. Some id's are not required (are nullable) for example :

```
rowId item1Id, item2Id, item3Id (item3Id can be null)
```

After we join this two tables we get id's and names. But if item3 Id is null that row is not shown.

Some data:

> Table1
>
> rowId, item1Id, item2Id, item3Id
>
> 1, 2, 3, 4
>
> 2, 1, 5, NULL

In our case we get as result one row ( 1 row)

So if it's null than it doesnt exists in Table2 and the row is not shown, but we would like to display null. 
So when we left join these two tables the result should have 2 rows.

This is the sql :

```
SELECT Recipes.recipeId, Recipes.userId,Users.firstName + ' ' + Users.lastName as userName,  servingTypeId,
Codings.coding as servingType, categoryId, Codings_2.coding as healthAspects, continentId,
Codings_3.coding as continent, countryId, CodingsAssociated.coding as country, typeOfPreparationId,
Codings_4.coding as typeOfPreparation, flavourId, Codings_5.coding as flavour, preparationSkillId,
Codings_6.coding as preparationSkill, seasonId,  activePreparationTime,
overallPreparationTime, isLocalDelight, servings, Codings_7.coding as season ,
calories, youTubeId, datePosted, isComposite, Recipes.isApproved, Recipes.timestamp, title,
localDelightRegion, otherFeatures, cookingInstructions 
      FROM Recipes LEFT OUTER JOIN

      Codings ON Recipes.servingTypeId = Codings.codingKeyId LEFT OUTER JOIN
      Codings as Codings_2 ON Recipes.categoryId = Codings_2.codingKeyId LEFT OUTER JOIN
      Codings as Codings_3 ON Recipes.continentId = Codings_3.codingKeyId LEFT OUTER JOIN
      CodingsAssociated ON Recipes.countryId = CodingsAssociated.codingKeyId LEFT OUTER JOIN
      Codings as Codings_4 ON Recipes.typeOfPreparationId = Codings_4.codingKeyId LEFT OUTER JOIN
      Codings as Codings_5 ON Recipes.flavourId = Codings_5.codingKeyId LEFT OUTER JOIN
      Codings as Codings_6 ON Recipes.preparationSkillId = Codings_6.codingKeyId LEFT OUTER JOIN
      Codings as Codings_7 ON Recipes.seasonId = Codings_7.codingKeyId  LEFT OUTER JOIN
      RecipesTranslations ON Recipes.recipeId = RecipesTranslations.recipeId LEFT OUTER JOIN
      Users ON Recipes.userId = Users.userId

      WHERE CodingsAssociated.languageId = @languageId AND Codings.languageId = @languageId
      AND Codings_2.languageId = @languageId AND Codings_3.languageId = @languageId
      AND Codings_4.languageId = @languageId AND
      Codings_5.languageId = @languageId AND Codings_6.languageId = @languageId AND RecipesTranslations.languageId = @languageId
      AND Codings_7.languageId = @languageId
```

For example because seasonId is sometimes null the join for Codings_7.coding is not shown, but I won`t to show also these rows where ids are null that the name also be null.

Comment: Left join will do what you want. But if you filter the tables on table2 columns you will effectively revert to inner join. All such filters should be moved to ON clause.

Comment: It is difficult to tell, what is being asked here, but I figure you need to do an outer join, and from the tsql tag I suppose you use MS SQL server, so here you go: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213228(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: Do you really need the whole query to demonstrate the problem?  Table1 and item3Id are not in the posted query.

Comment: Have you tried just changing `WHERE CodingsAssociated.languageId = @languageId AND Codings.languageId = @languageId` to `AND CodingsAssociated.languageId = @languageId AND Codings.languageId = @languageId`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by [Nikola Markovinović](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1231866/nikola-markovinovic) you need to move the where conditions to the join conditions

here your select corrected:

```
SELECT
   Recipes.recipeId,
   Recipes.userId,
   ---
   cookingInstructions 
FROM
   Recipes
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Codings ON
      Recipes.servingTypeId = Codings.codingKeyId AND
      Codings.languageId = @languageId
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Codings as Codings_2 ON 
      Recipes.categoryId = Codings_2.codingKeyId AND
      Codings_2.languageId = @languageId
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Codings as Codings_3 ON
      Recipes.continentId = Codings_3.codingKeyId AND
      Codings_3.languageId = @languageId
   LEFT OUTER JOIN CodingsAssociated ON
      Recipes.countryId = CodingsAssociated.codingKeyId AND
      CodingsAssociated.languageId = @languageId 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Codings as Codings_4 ON
      Recipes.typeOfPreparationId = Codings_4.codingKeyId AND
      Codings_4.languageId = @languageId
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Codings as Codings_5 ON
      Recipes.flavourId = Codings_5.codingKeyId AND
      Codings_5.languageId = @languageId
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Codings as Codings_6 ON
      Recipes.preparationSkillId = Codings_6.codingKeyId AND
      Codings_6.languageId = @languageId
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Codings as Codings_7 ON
      Recipes.seasonId = Codings_7.codingKeyId AND
      Codings_7.languageId = @languageId
   LEFT OUTER JOIN RecipesTranslations ON
      Recipes.recipeId = RecipesTranslations.recipeId AND
      RecipesTranslations.languageId = @languageId
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Users ON
      Recipes.userId = Users.userId ;
```

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to tell, what is being asked here, but I figure you need to do an outer join, and from the tsql tag I suppose you use MS SQL server, so here you go: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213228(v=sql.80).aspx

e.g.:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 a LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 b 
ON a.id_to_join_on = b.id_to_join_on
```

Comment: I try this and change INNER JOIN with LEFT OUTER JOIN but the rows that contains seasinId null, are not shown ( it can not show season if season id is null but I want that if it is null it shows also season name null) if you understand

Comment: I'm sorry, there is no seasinId in your select statement that you posted, so I still do not understand. Lets try to narrow down this problem to left-joining just two tables. So which table contains `seasionID` and which table contains `season_name` ?